# Does 'yield return new WaitForSeconds(4.0f)' have to charge?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I am making a First Person Shooter.

I want that my gun reloads, there plays an animation and after 4 seconds the number of bullets will be displayed. But sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't wait and displays the bullets immediately without playing the animation.

```
IEnumerator waitForReload()
{
    if (reloadNow==true && !gun.GetComponent<Animation>().IsPlaying("Reload"))
    {
        animator.SetInteger ("Anumber", reload);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (4.0f);
        reloadNow = false;
        displayBullets (); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Does 'yield return new WaitForSeconds(4.0f)' have to charge?"?

Comment: I mean that the waitforseconds need to pass 4 before he can do his work again.

Comment: wherever the WaitForSeconds is placed is where it will pause for set seconds? Meaning it will hit animator.SetInteger first instantly on function call, then it will wait 4 seconds, and then it will set reloadNow to false and call the displayBullets function.

Comment: where you are callig this waitforReload?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using the Animation component, you'll be after the Animator. They do similar things, except the Animator is Unity's newer and more improved version. Grabbing the Animation component and checking IsPlaying won't tell you whether the animation is playing, as the animation is being played through the Animator component.

First thing to check is your co-routines, how often are you firing them? The logic within is sound, however, you would ideally not start the co-routine again if you are reloading.

The yield in the co-routine is where the magic happens. Each time you yield, the function remembers it's location, so when you execute the function again it will pick up from where you left off. Each time you call StartCoroutine, a new routine is created.

So, if you accidentally start the co-routine again, you'll have multiple instances of it running, which is why it is potentially glitching out in certain places.
I'd recommend whacking some debugs in, put one in where you start the co-routine and one when you finish. If your console is getting spammed, then you know that you're starting it incorrectly and would either have to stop it from firing when it shouldn't or by starting the co-routine, and ending it if your checks say no.

```
if(reloading == false)
{
     reloading = true; 
     StartCoroutine(waitForReload());
}
else
{
    //do nothing
}

IEnumerator waitForReload()
{
    //your custom reload logic here
    reloading = false;

    //set reloading to false so we can reload again later, after the time is up in your case
}
```

Something along those lines should give you the intended result.

For the yield command, here's a reference
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

For the animator component:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo.html

This'll give you back the current animation clip that is playing, so you can check names that way.

Hopefully this'll lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem occurs because your coroutine runs more than once, try this (assuming your animation is 4 seconds long)

```
IEnumerator waitForReload()
{
    if (reloadNow)
    {
        animator.SetInteger ("Anumber", reload);
        reloadNow = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (4.0f);
        displayBullets (); 
    }
}
```

or preferably you can call the function that displays the bullets at the end of your animation

[image: Aniamtion event]

Comment: Okay, but if I try that are there no functions available.

Comment: the class that responsible for displaying the bullets should be attached to the same gameobject as the animator is attached to

Comment: I removed the waitforseconds method and I have replaced it for an animation event. But now I have another problem. Sorry for my bad English by the way, I am Dutch. Anyway, it works sometimes, but sometimes all the animations of my game stop and the bullets aren't displayed.